# Calculate proportions of exponentially weighted factors avoiding underflow problem

Tags: numerical-analysis, python, efficiency, numerical-limitations

I am trying to implement in Python this ratio:
$\frac{w_t(i)}{\sum w_t(j)}$ where $w_t(i) = w_{t-1}(i)\cdot\exp{(-x_{t}(i))}$, i.e. the weights are exponentially decreasing without running into underflow problems. I am using this ratio in a formula later. Has anyone had the same problem? Any ideas? I read a bit about the logsumexp trick but I am not sure I can use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may somewhat depend on your application. In general you can keep track of log-weights to minimize underflow issues (i.e. [log-likelihoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Log-likelihood); then the "logsumexp trick" could apply to the log of your normalization factor). However  some weights will still effectively go to 0 eventually. In [particle filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter#Sequential_importance_resampling_.28SIR.29) this is known as the "sample degeneracy problem", and is typically solved with *resampling* (e.g. as in the bootstrap filter described in the above link).